# Problema com manipulação de objeto em função forEach - Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, json

Estou tentando fazer uma manipulação de objeto em javascript, mas não está dando certo conforme esperado.

O código é esse:

```
let data = [{
    "Código": "COD01",
    "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100",
}, {
    "Código": "COD02",
    "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100",
}];

let newData = [];
data.forEach(function(produto) {
    newData.push(produto);

    if (produto["Opções de Tamanho"].indexOf('-') > -1) {
        let variacoes = produto["Opções de Tamanho"].split('-');
        let prodVariacao = produto;
        variacoes.forEach(function(variacao) {

            prodVariacao["Código"] = prodVariacao["Código"] + '-' + variacao;
            newData.push(prodVariacao);
            console.log(prodVariacao);
        });
    }
});

console.log('Novos dados:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(newData, null, 4));
```

A intenção era sair da seguinte forma na variável `newData`:

```
[
    {
        "Código": "COD01",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD01-85",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD01-90",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD01-95",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD01-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02-85",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02-90",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02-95",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    }
]
```

Mas está saindo dessa forma:

```
[
    {
        "Código": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Código": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Opções de Tamanho": "85-90-95-100"
    }
]
```

Já tentei resolver de diversas formas o problema, tanto com jQuery quanto javascript. Tentei também fazendo a cópia do objeto, pois parece que ele está fazendo a alteração em cima de outra alteração, ao invés de pegar o objeto base, porém eu não consegui resolver. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver o problema alterando a linha `let prodVariacao = produto;` para `let prodVariacao = structuredClone(produto);` e colocando ela dentro do segundo loop.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).